# javascript syntax for class issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok I have this javascript...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#holder').toggleClass("visible");

    $('a.link').click(function(event) {
        // Over-rides the link
        event.preventDefault();
        // Sets the new destination to the href of the link
        newLocation = this.href;
        color = $(this).data("color");
        $('body').css('background-color', color );
        $('#holder').css('opacity','0' );
        // Delays action
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            // Redirects to new destination
                window.location = newLocation;
        }, 250);
    });

    $('h1').click(function(event) {
        $('#holder').toggleClass("visible");
    });

});
```

and I have this html .......

```
<body class="landingpage">

    <h1 class="begining">Page Tansitions</h1>
    <p><a class="link" href="/one.html" data-color="#f36c20">Page One</a></p>
    <p><a class="link" href="/two.html" data-color="#edcd40">Page Two</a></p>

</body>
```

... That's all fine and dandy and the js does its thing and changes the color of the page which is ref 'body' in the code above....

I don't want to change the 'body' tag of a html page I want to change a class something like .metro .tile-area-darkCrimson  as referenced in my css and   in my html...  I can't for the life of me figure out how to present it in javascript can someone please help.

Cheers,
Greg.

.... Further to that I have attempted to integrate it into a more complex structure that now doesn't seem to work ... I have   link for the html where I am using a tile class and animation that do work without any changes.....

```
<a class="tile double bg-tile1color live animated flipInX link" data-color="#f36c20" data-role="live-tile" data-effect="slideUp" data-click="transform">
```

I am also using a javascript trigger when the user clicks on this tile and that is where I want to slot in the aforementioned javascript that changes the page color..I am guessing the javascript is overiding the transition....

```
<script>          
$('.tile').on('click', function () {

    $(".tile").addClass("flipOutX");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".tile-group.main").css({ marginLeft:"-40px", width: "1080px"}).load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
    }, 2000);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery you can use full css selection methods

```
$('body').css('background-color', color );
```

Can be something like this

```
$('.metro .tile-area-darkCrimson').css('background-color', color );
```

Comment: that would work and as you have guessed this is for one box or button I have created with <a></a>  ..... if I were to have many buttons would I just copy and paste it and give the top of the function a unique class name such as a.link1, a.link2 etc  .....referencing this bit from the js ... 
    $('a.link').click(function(event) {
        // Over-rides the link
        event.preventDefault();

Comment: i can only do one every 90 minutes so I will have to wait until tomorrow ... thanks for your help buddy

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```
$('body').addClass('metro tile-area-darkCrimson');
```

Comment: does that refer to the css and html iteractions of that with the correct syntax , i notice you use no dots to seperate the classes

Comment: Correct, if you read through the page I linked, you'll see "More than one class may be added at a time, separated by a space"

Comment: it bl***y worked though didn't it !!! legend !!! ....... why no dots then is that just a jquery derivation ?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to use selector notation, you just need to pass in the class names separated by spaces if there are multiple.

Comment: It's going to be hard to work through that problem in the comments. If this answer works for you, I would accept it and then create another question.

Comment: agreed I will do just that